# Integer solutions to $ x+y=|x||y| $

Tags: number-theory, functions

I need to find the number of integer solutions to the equation $ xy=x+y $.Also I need to show that all the non-integral solutions lie exactly on two lines.I need to find the lines.

I could just manually find some solutions to the equation like $x=2,y=2$ and $x=0,y=0$.After that I'm having trouble proceeding.Any suggestions ?

Comment: The lines are $x=\frac{x}{y-1}$, where $y>1$ and $x=\frac{y}{y+1}$ where $y>-1$

Answer (score 5):

Temporarily ignoring the absolute values, you can rewrite

$$x+y=\pm xy$$ or $$(x\pm1)(y\pm1)=1.$$

So the integer solutions are those giving a positive sum among

$$\begin{align}x+1&=y+1=+1,\\
x+1&=y+1=-1,\\
x-1&=y-1=+1,\\
x-1&=y-1=-1.\end{align}
$$

The non-integer solutions are equilateral hyperbolas.

Comment: I think you mean "non-negative" sum, rather than than "positive."

Comment: @BarryCipra: yes, I do.

Comment: Yves, yes, you agree with me, or yes, you meant what you wrote?  If the latter, what sum are you referring to?  I took it to mean the sum $x+y$.

Comment: @BarryCipra: $x+y\ge0$, as you know.

Comment: Which means the sum is non-negative, not positive, as *you* know! (I'm just wondering why you didn't make the edit.  I'll delete all this if/when you do.)

Answer (score 1):

Among integer solutions, if $x\le-1$, then $y=|x||y|-x\ge|y|+1$, which is impossible, so $x\ge0$.  By symmetry, $y\ge0$ also.  Thus we can drop the absolute value signs and simply write $x+y=xy$, which can be rewritten as

$$(x-1)(y-1)=1$$

It's easy to see that $x=y=0$ and $x=y=2$ are the only (integer) solutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$x+y=|x||y|$$
in integers.

---

Case 1.
$x=0$ or $y=0$.

If one of them is 0, the second one also has to be, so $x=y=0$.

Case 2. $x,y>0$.

Then we have equation $y=x(y-1)$, obviously $y\neq 1$ and since $y-1$ and $y$ are relatively prime, we have to have $y-1=1$, so $y=2$, then $x=2$.

Case 3. -- last case -- $x+y$ has to be positive now, so the case is $x>0>y$ or $y>0>x$, by symmetry let it be $x>0>y$. Let $z=-y$, then $z$ is a positive integer and we have equation $x-z=xz$, or $x=x(z+1)$,  $1=z+1$, $z=0$ - contradiction.

Hence $(0,0)$ and $(2,2)$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using case analysis. I'll do one let $x \gt 0, y \gt 0$ then $x+y=xy$ so $y=\frac{x}{x-1}$ and we have the set of solutions , $(t,\frac{t}{t-1})$ but $\frac{t}{t-1}$ is only integer if $t=2$ so we get the solution $2,2$.

Answer (score 0):

The given equation can be re-written as,

$$ y = \frac{x}{x-1}$$

This equation clearly shows that y can be an integer only if RHS has integral values which is possible only for 0 and 2, that is x = 0 or x - 1 is 1 ie. x = 2. Thus, it has no other integer solutions.